# Mongoose: deleteOne middleware para un delete en cascada no funciona

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, middleware

tengo una situación que no puedo resolver. Te un modelo que guarda una en una coleccion canciones y por otro lado tengo un modelo de usario que dentro tiene un campo que es un array que guarda los id de las canciones que el admin le permite escuchar. Lo que necesito hacer es que cuando se elimine una canción de la base de datos tambien se eliminen en audioList de todos los usuarios que contienen su id dentro del array.
Intenté usar un middleware pre pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Este ese el modelo de las canciones:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Category = require("../models/categorySchema");
const User = require("../models/userSchema");


const audioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    artist: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    duration: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
        trim: true
    }
}, {timestamps : true});


const Audio = mongoose.model("Audio", audioSchema);

module.exports = Audio;
```

y este es el modelo de los usuarios:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Audio = require("../models/audioSchema");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: "user",
        enum: ["user", "admin"]
    },
    whatsapp: {
        type: String
    },
    audioList: [{
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "Audio"
        }],
    state: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    }
}, {timestamps : true});


// Middleware para eliminar el ID del audio de la lista de audio de los usuarios
userSchema.pre('findByIdAndDelete', async function (next) {
    console.log("entro al pre")
    try {
        // Buscar y eliminar el ID del audio de la lista de audio de todos los usuarios
        await this.model('User').updateMany(
            { audioList: this._id },
            { $pull: { audioList: this._id } }
        );
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

y este es el controlador para eliminar canciones:

```
const delAudio = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    try {
        // Buscar el audio por ID
        const audio = await Audio.findById(id);
        if (!audio) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                mensaje: 'El audio no existe',
                status: 404
            });
        }
        // Obtener el public_id de Cloudinary desde la URL del audio
        const publicId = audio.url.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
        // Eliminar el archivo de Cloudinary
        await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(publicId, {resource_type: 'video'})
        .then(result=>console.log(result));
        // Utilizar findByIdAndDelete para activar los middleware
        await Audio.findByIdAndDelete(id);
        return res.status(200).json({
            mensaje: 'Audio eliminado correctamente',
            status: 200
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({
            mensaje: 'Hubo un error, intente más tarde',
            status: 500,
            error: error.message
        });
    }
};
```